# How to redirect to a page on successful payment in Laravel

Tags: laravel

I'm using Stripe with Laravel and its working fine. I'm using a modal to show the inputs of the required credit card, and all I want is to redirect to a success page if the payment was made, and the user cant access to this page if he used the link, it's like if the user is login otnot login like using auth.

**StripeController**

```php
public function stripePost(Request $request)
{
    Stripe\Stripe::setApiKey(env('STRIPE_SECRET'));
    Stripe\Charge::create([
        "amount" => 100 * 100,
        "currency" => "usd",
        "source" => $request->stripeToken
    ]);

    Session::flash('success', 'Payment successful!');

    return back();
}

Route::get('/paymentdone', 'StripePaymentController@paymentdone');
```

**success.blade.php**

```html
<p>success</p>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the `stripePost()` method, why don't you redirect to the specific route you've defined like this:

```
return redirect()->to('/paymentdone');
```

and then in the controller `StripePaymentController` method `paymentdone()`, check for existence of the session and show the success view or throw an error like this:

```
public function paymentdone() {
    if (session()->has('success')) {
        return view('success');
    }

    app()->abort(401);
}
```

Comment: p.s. I don't know how the stripe library works; buy you should always check the result calling the `Stripe\Charge::create(...);` to see if it actually worked before redirecting.

Answer (score 0):

Most of the Payment Gateway, if you are not making the payment in your website, have a redirect url to redirect back to your website with a message. If this is your case, for sure you have to set up the back url when creating the payment.

If the payment is processed by you:

instead to use return back();

```
return redirect()->route('payment.done');
```

and your route:

```
Route::get('/paymentdone', 'StripePaymentController@paymentdone')->name('payment.done');
```

For your method stripePost() you could [create a request](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/validation#form-request-validation) to validate the data.

```
public function stripePost(StripeRequest $request){
    // Retrieve the validated input data...
    $validated = $request->validated();
}
```